# Modify the query that generates the exposed form element in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I would like to change the dropdown filter in a view, by modifying the query that generates it. I do not want to modify the form values after they got pouplated with data already, because it is huge list.

Is there a hook like this view-query modifier for the exposed filter generation query?

```
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think views offers such a hook. A comprehensive list of views hooks can be found here: [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7). Drupal does however offer an [out of the box hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7) for altering queries `hook_query_alter($query)` that should be able to modify the query before it is executed.